# "No such file or directory" discord.py - FileNotFound is not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a Discord bot with sound functions (like a soundboard). The command should play a sound, which the user types in the command. If the Sound doesn't exist, it should send a message, that it doesn't exist. But if the Error *lib/media/sounds/foo.mp3: No such file or directory*  occurs it doesn't react and doesn't send a message.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1,5,commands.BucketType.user)
async def sound(ctx, sound : str):
    await done(ctx)
    user = ctx.message.author
    if user.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("Du bist in keinem Sprachkanal")
        add_log('user is in no voice channel', cat=err)
    voiceChannel = user.voice.channel
    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice is None:
        await voiceChannel.connect()
        add_log('connected to: ' + str(voiceChannel), cat=i)
    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    try:
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f"lib/media/sounds/{sound}.mp3"))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        await ctx.send("Diesen Sound gibt es nicht!")
```

I hope thats enough information

Comment: That function must raise some other exception (or perhaps no exception at all) when the sound file is not found.  Call the function without using try/except and see what exception is raised.

Comment: Without try/except its the same error as with try/except (lib/media/sounds/foo.mp3: No such file or directory)

Comment: `No such file or directory` That's the error _message_.  What is the exception _type_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FFmpegPCMAudio](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#ffmpegpcmaudio) calls ffmpeg in a subprocess, that's why Python doesn't raise FileNotFound.

*If you check the docs (linked) you will see the function raises ClientException. You must catch this exception for your code to work.* **EDIT: Apparently it doesn't raise any exception.**

You can check if the file exists using [os.path.isfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile)

Comment: So, I replaced FileNotFound with discord.ClientException, but it's still not working.

Comment: Hmm, weird, it's possible no exception gets raised. Can you just try using

`except Exception as e: print(e)`

and paste what gets printed to screen.

Comment: Code:     ```try:
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f"lib/media/sounds/{sound}.mp3"))
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        await ctx.send("Diesen Sound gibt es nicht!")``` `Exception: lib/media/sounds/foo.mp3: No such file or directory`     The print doesn't return anything

Comment: Wait, was "Exception" in `Exception: lib/media/sounds/foo.mp3: No such file or directory` before?

Comment: No, it wasn't. It was always `lib/media/sounds/foo.mp3: No such file or directory`. I added it. But with os.path.isfile it's working now. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it works!